# rbind two tables and fill NA's rows with values having same variable

Tags: r

im going to explain to you my question on base of the sample data. Here is first table **(df1)**:

```
  x x1 y  z
1 1 10 a 11
2 3 11 b 13
3 5 10 c 15
4 7 11 d 17
5 9 10 e 19
```

here is a `dput()` version:

```
structure(list(x = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), x1 = c(10, 11, 10, 11, 10
), y = structure(1:5, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), 
    z = c(11, 13, 15, 17, 19)), .Names = c("x", "x1", "y", "z"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

and second table **(df2)**:

```
  x x1
1 2 10
2 3 60
```

`dput()`:

```
structure(list(x = c(2, 3), x1 = c(10, 60)), .Names = c("x", 
"x1"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to now bind rows of these two tables and fill the missing column values with values from **df1**. Let me explain you on base of these two tables.

At first i use `smartbind()` function from `gtools` library:

```
library(gtools)
data <- smartbind(df1, df2)
```

And the result that i get looks like that:

```
 x x1    y  z
 1 10    a 11
 3 11    b 13
 5 10    c 15
 7 11    d 17
 9 10    e 19
 2 10 <NA> NA
 3 60 <NA> NA
```

So i would like to fill up the all NA values which appear in the rows from df2, with df1 values if the **x is the same**. In this case it would look like that:

```
 x x1    y  z
 1 10    a 11
 3 11    b 13
 5 10    c 15
 7 11    d 17
 9 10    e 19
 2 10 <NA> NA
 3 60    b 13
```

In my original dataset i do have around 280 columns! Thanks for help

**Is there any more ELEGANT way to do it rather then joining two data frames and then using rbind()**

Comment: Seems like a duplicate to me: first you have to merge by `x` and select all `df2` records and only then use  `rbind`. [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: is there any more elegant way to do it? i knew i could do it with merging and then using rbind, but it doesnt seem much elegant and efficient if i have huge tables (columns > 280, rows > 10000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   select(-x1) %>% 
   right_join(df2) %>%
   bind_rows(df1, .)
#  x x1    y  z
#1 1 10    a 11
#2 3 11    b 13
#3 5 10    c 15
#4 7 11    d 17
#5 9 10    e 19
#6 2 10 <NA> NA
#7 3 60    b 13
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df1), c('x', 'x1'))
setDT(df2)[df1, (nm1) := mget(nm1), on = .(x)]
rbind(df1, df2)
#   x x1    y  z
#1: 1 10    a 11
#2: 3 11    b 13
#3: 5 10    c 15
#4: 7 11    d 17
#5: 9 10    e 19
#6: 2 10 <NA> NA
#7: 3 60    b 13
```

Answer (score 5):

First you can merge missing columns of df2 from df1, only keeping extra columns( `y` and `z`, and the key column `x` from df1):

```
df2 = merge(df2,df1[,c("x","y","z")],by="x",all.x=T)
```

and then rbind df1 and df2:

```
> rbind(df1,df2)
  x x1    y  z
1 1 10    a 11
2 3 11    b 13
3 5 10    c 15
4 7 11    d 17
5 9 10    e 19
6 2 10 <NA> NA
7 3 60    b 13
```

Comment: Just use `df1[, -2]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i am looking for more elegant way to do it, maaybe with data.table?

Comment: @PoGibas You're right but keeping it like this since column names are more comprehensible for demo purposes.

Comment: @Mal_a you can wrap up the above process in a function to your taste and come up with your own elegant solution :) (PS: I guess columns > 280, rows > 10000 is no big deal for merge and rbind)